# How to Run SignalR service as a Server in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a requirement were I need to run SignalR server in Xamarin app, and consume it in web app. As far as I have seen in examples, Xamarin is used as a client consuming the SignalR. Can anyone help me how to register and start SignalR in Xamarin like we do in dotnet core app as below

```
services.AddSignalR();

app.UseSignalR(routes => {
   routes.MapHub<HubName>("path");
});
```

Is there a way were I can run same/alternative code in Xamarin. Thanks

Comment: Any updates on this please?

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Your above code, those are used in asp.net core webapp. What I currently know is that you can use [SingalR Self-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host) to achieve your needs, but it seems that .net core cannot be used, because the official documents are based on .net framework.

Official sample uses the console application, and [this article uses windows service](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881511/SignalR-with-Self-hosted-Windows-Service).

By using `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost` package can achieve your needs.

Comment: I think the question is about ASP.NET Core SignalR.